# Vue-select not displaying the text after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

i am using vue-select component, everything looks fine but the selected value is not shown at the top after user selects an option here is the gif screen to get an idea what is happening please see the the GIF below

> GIF (https://ibb.co/fxJvzFn)

when the user selects their account, getSpreadSheets (googlesheet component method) is executed to get all sheets names in user google drive.
data is showing properly in the dropdown (as seen in the GIF) and value is also stored in the vue modal (**fielddata.spreadsheetId**) but i don't know why does it not displaying the selected text

```
getSpreadSheets: function() {

        if(!this.fielddata.googleaccountID) {
            return;
        }

        var that = this;
        this.listLoading = true;
        var listRequestData = {
            'action': 'awp_get_spreadsheet_list',
            'accountid':this.fielddata.googleaccountID,
            '_nonce': awp.nonce
        };
        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, listRequestData, function( response ) {
            that.$set(that.fielddata, 'spreadsheetList', vueArrayObjectMaker(response.data));
            //that.fielddata.spreadsheetList = vueArrayObjectMaker(response.data);
            that.listLoading = false;

        });
        
    },
```

**vueArrayObjectMaker** function is there to convert the response from an object to an Array of objects
the actual response is in this format {key:value,key:value,key:value} i am changing it to [{key:value},{key:value},{key:value}] as this is the required format from vue

```
function vueArrayObjectMaker(data){
if( 
typeof data === 'object' &&
!Array.isArray(data) &&
data !== null){

    let objectsArray = [];
    let lists = data;
    for (var key in lists) {
        if (lists.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            objectsArray.push({id: key, name: lists[key]});
        }
    }

    return objectsArray;
}


return data;
}
```

this is the googlesheet action template where this vue-select component is used

Add Spreadsheet

```
<li>
<span>Spreadsheets</span>

<vue-select placeholder="Select Spreadsheet..." :options="fielddata.spreadsheetList"
label="name" :reduce="obj => obj.id" v-model="fielddata.spreadsheetId"></vue-select>

<div class="spinner" v-bind:class="{'is-active': listLoading}"></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the 'spreadsheetId' under data instead of under fileddata, because vue can't detect the change of porperty of the object.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    spreadsheetId: ''
  }
})
```